# Convert datetime column value from SQL Server in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to convert a datetime column from my SQL Server to date in my vb.net program. I am importing my column with a SQL query from my vb.net source but I don't know how to convert it to date? Any ideas?

```
adapter_view.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [action_date] from table_1"
```

The thing is that my columns has hours minutes etc I want to get only the date from that column.

Comment: Can you post some of the VB.Net code you are using? You should not need to do any conversion.

Comment: You don't need to convert anything. Read the sql `datetime` into a vb.net `datetime` variable.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå i wnt to get only the date not the time etc

Comment: There's no "date only" class in .net. Note that there's a difference between how a value is stored and how it's displayed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONVERT(varchar,b.[Action Date],101) as Action_Date
```

With that code i convert my datetime to date format

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),Action_Date,101) as Action_Date from Table
```